# How can I get autocomplete in Google Apps Script for standard JavaScript functions

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete

How can I get autocomplete in Google Apps Script for standard JavaScript functions
for example if
after following line

```
var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
```

If I type `re.`then I should get suggestions re member functions/data.

Comment: There's been an [outstanding issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1080) for several years asking for extension of the autocomplete feature to cover standard JS in the GAS editor. Two options exist: develop in the editor w/o standard JS autocompletion, or in Eclipse w/o support for the GAS built-ins. Two bad answers for the price of one. ANYWAY... you could raise that as a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues), as it's a support issue, not a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

As things are right now there are two ways to go:

1. Become a developer at google and lobby your way to building and delivering your own implementation.
2. Open an issue with google and hope for the best.

There's no support in the GAS for standard JavaScript auto-completion as is. You can work around it by coding in another IDE than the provided one and then paste it in, or build your own GAS IDE that supports only the JS supported by GAS.

Comment: update ! G-suit App maker has now support of autocomplete even on external libs. google app script is still cant autocomplete in the way described in this question .